# Pushing two UIViewControllers with a single URL in TTNavigator (Three20)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, three20

I am working on a core data app with three20. I have a specific situation where I have to show the Detailed View on an entity when a launcher button is clicked. I also want to push the list of all the entities before I push this detail view. To be more specific this is what I want to accomplish.

1. When the Launcher button is clicked I want to open the Table View that has list of all the entities.
2. Then push the Detailed view of the specific entity.

Is this possible in three20 with a single URL for the Launcher Item? Is there any other way to accomplish this?

I tried looking at various ways of doing it but I was not able to accomplish this. Can anybody suggest any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a single URL, but in the `viewDidAppear` method, you can call

```
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:<YOUR_SECOND_PATH>] applyAnimated:YES]];
```

If you want them both to animate, other wise call it in `viewDidLoad` as

```
 [[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:<YOUR_SECOND_PATH>]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wont have access to my mac till later today. I think this solution should work!